# touches ended/After dragging is completed, i need to check, if the dragged image frame touches any of my 100 images frame

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimageview

i have 100 UIViews in UIViewController class . i am dragging a separate imageView over my 100 UIviews.

when touches ended/dragging completed, i need to check, if the dragged image frame touches any of my 100 UIViews frame.

is there any way to check it. I have given tags to my each 100 UiViews.

Is there any easy way to get it the UIView Details.(than 100 switch conditions).

eg:

```
CGPoint touchEndpoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
CGPoint imageEndpoint = [touch locationInView:imageview];
 if(CGRectContainsPoint([imageview frame], touchEndpoint))
 {
```

Comment: I have one suggestion for you. when you add 100 views on parent view than why not 100 buttons with unique tag over that all views, and when with the click event of that button you can manage that view and that after move that view also for dragging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your UIViews to an NSMutableArray (myViews in the example) then you can do...

```
for(UIView *aView in myViews) {
  if(CGRectContainsPoint([myView frame], touchEndPoint)) {
    //DO STUFF
  }
}
```